# HEX to RGB in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I need any solutions on how to convert HTML HEX color value to RGB and then output RGB values as string to label/edit. So, for example if input is #FFFFFF the output would be 255,255,255. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use [`Get[R|G|B]Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144923(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I commented the same, and then I realized the value is `#FFFFFF` which is not the same as a Delphi `TColor` such as `$00ffffff`... So I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Jerry - Why not? The most significant byte is always 0 for a non-system color. BTW, the functions in windows.pas is actually the equivalent of their API conterparts.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz `#FFFFFF` is invalid syntax in pascal, won't even compile. Perhaps OP got this value out of HTML?

Comment: @Jerry - In that case it's not actually a hex color value as the question notes.

Comment: @Jerry: #FFFFFF appears to be an HTML color value, which is the same as $FFFFFF in Delphi, which is a valid RGB color value.

Comment: That is exactly my point, the question is not clear. OP states it's a "HEX color", but not how Delphi handles such.

Comment: @Jerry: Was just about to add that to my comment to you. You were quicker. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, my thought as well, a string.

Comment: @Ken I never said it's not a valid RGB color value - just not a Delphi HEX color. It's most likely a string.

Comment: Perhaps the asker should ask a question on replacing the first character with a $. And then converting a string to an integer.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Where does the `#FFFFFF` *HEX color* come from? It's not a Delphi hex value, which would be `$FFFFFF`. Are you asking about an HTML color value? Are you asking to convert it to three bytes for R, G, and B, or a string that contains `255,255,255`?  Please [edit] your post to be more clear. When doing so, please remember that we can't read your mind, so we have no idea what you're asking unless you put it into your question, so *be specific* about what you're asking.

Comment: Delphi `TColor` also has an alpha channel though, making it 4 bytes, not 3. As my first comment mentions, Delphi TColor format is `$00ffffff`

Comment: See [How to Convert a HTML Hex Color to TColor](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=44649).

Comment: @Jerry - That's not alpha, it's a code for a system color.

Comment: @Jerry: $FFFFFF is a totally valid color value in Delphi. Try it in the Object Inspector. So is $FFFF or $FF.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Okay but still, the point is that the value in the question above, as it's currently written (with `#`) is not a valid TColor in Delphi.

Comment: @Jerry it is. The sys-color code is 0, meaning it's an RGB value.

Comment: YES, but have you tried putting `#FFFFFF` into Delphi? Doesn't work. THAT is what I'm saying. The `#` makes it invalid in Delphi.

Comment: @Jerry - I didn't see the #, or you edited later. Perhaps we should comment slower. :)

Comment: **HTML Codes format:** 
Each HTML code contains symbol "#" and 6 letters or numbers. These numbers are in hexadecimal numeral system. For example "FF" in hexadecimal represents number 255 in Decimal. 

**Meaning of symbols:** 
The first two symbols in HTML color code represents the intensity of red color. 00 is the least and FF is the most intense. The third and fourth represents intensity of green and fifth and sixth represents the intensity of blue. So with combining the intensity of red, green and blue we can mix almost any color that our heart desire;)

Comment: I don't understand all the arguing, my very first comment is still correct. The value, as stated in this question "`#FFFFFF`" is **NOT** valid in Delphi. I stated this before I even edited that comment.

Comment: @Jerry, it may be if you've set `HexDisplayPrefix` accordingly. At least as a string..

Comment: @JerryDodge, its looks like a valid html hex color string, as my links and comments suggests.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That's an awkward feature I've never heard of before. Sure, I guess in that case someone *could* tweak their Delphi to use `#` instead of `$`.

Comment: @LURD My first comment, which everyone is arguing about, was a response to the prior comment, to use `GetRValue` ... etc. which will not work on the particular value provided by OP in the question. I'm done arguing for no apparent reason. Goodbye before I say something stupid.

Comment: @Jerry - It's probably only for converting to hex string. Dunno, never looked into what it is...

Comment: Here is a link to my quote above: [HTML Color Codes](http://html-color-codes.info/). If you parse html code for a color string, like in `<body style="background:#80BFFF">` you end up with `#80BFFF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question (Question somewhat shortened)

> I need HEX color value to  label/edit -color.  e.g. #FFFFFF the output
>   would be 255,255,255.

**If I understand the question correctly you want to assign a TEdit.Color a html hex value like #662233**

Delphi `Edit1.Color` or `label1.Color` can not handle 255,255,255 directly.

So you need a **$** Hex string like $00662233.

Here a short function how to.
The Input value of Edit1 must be validated: 
Instead of TLabel I use a TPanel.
Special settings are needed if you use a VCL Theme

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Conv: TButton;
    procedure ConvClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.ConvClick(Sender: TObject);
const
zeroV = '00000000';
begin
Edit1.Text  := StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'#','',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit2.Text  := '$'+Copy(zeroV,1,8-Length(Edit1.Text))+Edit1.Text;
Panel1.Color := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
end;
```

---

[image]

**Update**
If you want simple convert the hex to rgb use this.

```
procedure TForm1.RGBBtClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Edit1.Text  := StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'#','',[]);
(* The HTML order *)
Edit2.Text  := IntToStr(StrToInt('$'+Copy(Edit1.Text,1,2)))+','+
               IntToStr(StrToInt('$'+Copy(Edit1.Text,3,2)))+','+
               IntToStr(StrToInt('$'+Copy(Edit1.Text,5,2)));
(* or Reversed the Delphi order
Edit2.Text  := IntToStr(StrToInt('$'+Copy(Edit1.Text,5,2)))+','+
               IntToStr(StrToInt('$'+Copy(Edit1.Text,3,2)))+','+
               IntToStr(StrToInt('$'+Copy(Edit1.Text,1,2)));
*)
end;
```

You will get for Delphi order
**#35358B**

**139,53,53**

Look at the Image from the Color Picker
you will see in the RGB fields the same value.

or the HTML order is (Below the 35358B field)
**#8B3535**

So do not confuse this !
If you want to use html Color Codes in Delphi for a component color you have to use the Html Color Code in reverse.

[Html Color Codes](http://html-color-codes.info/)

Comment: *"output RGB values to label/edit"* probably means displaying the value in their captions. No mention of "Edit1.Color" or "label1.Color" in the question. I wonder if you've quoted another question, that quote does not exist in the question in this page, including previous revisions. Perhaps you've asked a question yourself and then answered it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz : I dont think OP wants: `displaying the value in their captions`. I think OP want's Label.Color just show the same Color as in a Html Browser

Comment: The update is problematic because it won't handle, e.g. #ff

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @VladSineok : you are welcome! And what part you are looking for ? Part one or the update part?

Comment: @moskito-x the update part was the one I was looking for, but also thanks for the part one, it may come in handy.

Comment: @VladSineok : Thanks for the info. Now you should edit your question to make it more clear. 23 comments below your question shows what I mean. Maybe one or the other will take his downvote back ;-)

Comment: the main thing here is: *If you want to use html Color Codes in Delphi for a component color you have to use the Html Color Code in reverse.*

thanks!